# Can't figure out my own code

Tags: c++, function, sfml

I'm having lots of trouble figuring out why my code isn't working. I don't have anyone else to turn to for help so I am hoping that someone here can help me.

I'm working on a game in C++ and I am needing my ground to cut away, so to speak. Here is my code as I have it now:

This is in my main.cpp:

```
if(en1.getBottom() > jello1.getGroundHeight())
    {
        jello1.setHealth(jello1.getHealth() - 25);
        jello1.setGroundHeight((int)screen1.getScreenDimensions().y (int)jello1.getSize().y);
    }

if(jello1.getHealth() == 75)
    {
        jello1.update1(jello1, lane1, screen1);
    }
```

This is my header for my Jello class:

```
#ifndef JELLO_H
#define JELLO_H

#include"ScreenDimensions.h"
#include"Lane.h"

class Jello
{
public:

    sf::RectangleShape ground;

    void update1(Jello jello, Lane lane, ScreenDimensions screen);

private:

    sf::Vector2f mPositionJello;
    sf::Vector2f mSizeJello;
    sf::Color mColorJello;
    int mGroundHeight;
    int mHealth;
};

#endif // JELLO_H
```

And this is my Jello.cpp file:

```
#include"Jello.h"

void Jello::update1(Jello jello, Lane lane, ScreenDimensions screen)
{
    jello.ground.setSize(sf::Vector2f((float)screen.getScreenDimensions().x / 8, 15.0f));
    jello.ground.setPosition(sf::Vector2f((float)lane.getLanePositionX(), (float)screen.getScreenDimensions().y - 10.0f));
}
```

I can't seem to find why my `update1` function will not work. I have written my code in another way that is only in my main.cpp but it is a lot of repeating code and I want it to look cleaner.

I tried to cut my code down to make this post shorter, but if it isn't clear, I can post all of my code to help.

Thanks in advance for anyone taking the time to read this and try and help me out.

Comment: at first glance: you should be passing your parameters by reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but at a quick glance: you are trying to make modifications  to your variables "jello, lane" etc. You should pass them by reference:

```
void update1(Jello &jello, Lane &lane, ScreenDimensions &screen);
```

(or using a pointer). some more information about [passing by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `jello` by value, which means you are creating a copy of the object and updating that rather than updating the object you passed in.

To fix this, just pass it by reference:

```
void Jello::update1(Jello &jello, const Lane &lane, const ScreenDimensions &screen)
//                        ^ here
```

You should pass the other two objects by const-reference to avoid unnecessary copying. Note that this will only work if the functions you call on those objects are declared `const`, which they probably should be.